# qt examples for studying

Tags: qt

somebody knows where can I find more examples like these ones

```
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/tutorial.html
```

I want to study qt, but I think that it is not helpful to read all classes from A to Z, need practice, thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation for next step is thinking of some small project you want to make and then looking up programs from http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html and especially http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/demos.html that demonstrates features you want. The demos are also a good way to learn good Qt usage and idioms, because they have a feeling of being more complete mini-programs.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently since I don't have enough rep to paste in more than 1 link, we had to do it this way..

- http://www.google.com/search?q=qt+tutorial
- http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/my-first-qt-gui-application.html
- http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLT7oEt6gLE
- http://thelins.se/learnqt/category/tutorial/